# How to filter data by comparing normal date to datetime with timezone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have some data stored in a db which I am accessing and filtering via flask and flask-sqlalchemy.

I am trying to filter the data based on `start` & `end` dates, which will be taken as user inputs from `request.args.get()` in the url. In the db, the data is of `"2020-05-12T00:00:00+02:00"` format and when the user enters the dates he will just enter the date and not the time or timezone (like: `2020-05-12`). So, based on the values entered by the user for `start` & `end` (`end` included), I would like to compare the date and return the values. The returned value must, however, have the original date format

The data looks as follows:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "value": 21.4,
            "start": "2020-05-12T00:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-12T01:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "value": 18.93,
            "start": "2020-05-12T01:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-12T02:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "value": 18.06,
            "start": "2020-05-13T02:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-13T03:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "value": 17.05,
            "start": "2020-05-13T03:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-13T04:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "value": 16.84,
            "start": "2020-05-14T04:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-14T05:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "value": 19.3,
            "start": "2020-05-14T05:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-14T06:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        }]}
```

**Example:**

If:

`start` is `2020-05-12` & `end` is `2020-05-14`, from the above data, the following data must be returned:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "value": 21.4,
            "start": "2020-05-12T00:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-12T01:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "value": 18.93,
            "start": "2020-05-12T01:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-12T02:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "value": 18.06,
            "start": "2020-05-13T02:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-13T03:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "value": 17.05,
            "start": "2020-05-13T03:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-13T04:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "value": 16.84,
            "start": "2020-05-14T04:00:00+02:00",
            "end": "2020-05-14T05:00:00+02:00",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "price_type": "DAY_AHEAD"
        }]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take values from `request.args.get()` as follows:

```
start_date = request.args.get('start')
end_date = request.args.get('end')
```

Then you can use [dateutil.parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to parse your date to [isoformat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) and then filter them:

```
start_date = dateutil.parser.parse(filters['start']).isoformat()
end_date = dateutil.parser.parse(filters['end']).isoformat()
items = YourModel.query.filter(YourModel.start >= start_date).filter(YourModel.end <= end_date)
```